# Errors while importing products from woocommerce in vue storefront

Tags: vue-storefront

I’m trying to create my first Vue storefront. I created a new wordpress site with woocommerce plugin.

Problem is that when I try to import products from woocommerce (using woocommerce2vuestorefront), there are some errors like

```
2019-09-11 17:59:37 warn: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse [created_at]
2019-09-11 17:59:37 warn: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse [created_at]
2019-09-11 17:59:37 warn: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse [created_at]
2019-09-11 17:59:37 info: 0 products were successfully imported.
```

the command which I’m using for importing products is

```
node cli.js products
```

and config.js in woocommerce2vuestorefront is like this

```
  woo: {
    api: {
      host: 'localhost/wordpress',
      protocol: 'http',
      auth: {
        consumer_key: "ck_c2bb899b85976683687d745a207cd2f8424d",
        consumer_secret: "cs_40f58a37c6408843dd15b22295db633b38",
        version: "v3"
      }
    }
  },
  db: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9200,
    driver: 'elasticsearch',
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'http://localhost:9200',
    indexName:  process.env.INDEX_NAME || 'vue_storefront_catalog'
  },
```

I think error is coming from elastic search but not sure how to fix it.

any help is highly appreciated.